# Flot not working with the node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, flot

I have a node.js server script which reads the data from serial port using web sockets and displays the data on a browser. The server script is absolutely fine as it displays correctly realtime data on the browser. This also means the websockets are also working correctly. The real problem starts when I tried to use Flot to display real time charts to visualize the data. The server throws error message -
   **debug - served static content /socket.io.js**

**Here is the the code for my server :**

```
// It captures data from serial port and displays it in web page.
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var sys = require('sys');
var fs = require('fs');
var clients = [];
http.listen(8000);

var SerialPort  = require('serialport2').SerialPort;
var portName = 'COM10';
var sp = new SerialPort(); // instantiate the serial port.
sp.open(portName, { // portName is instatiated to be COM3, replace as necessary
       baudRate: 9600, // this is synced to what was set for the Arduino Code
      dataBits: 8, // this is the default for Arduino serial communication
      parity: 'none', // this is the default for Arduino serial communication
      stopBits: 1, // this is the default for Arduino serial communication
      flowControl: false // this is the default for Arduino serial communication
   });
function handler(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type':'text/html'
    });
var rs = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/template2.htm');
sys.pump(rs, response);
};

var buffer ; //contains raw data
var dataStore = "" ; // To hold the string

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
var username;
clients.push(socket);
socket.emit('welcome', {'salutation':'TMP36 Sensor output!'});

sp.on('data', function (data) { // call back when data is received
    buffer = data.toString();
    // check for end character in buffer
    for(i=0; i<buffer.length; i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] != "N")
        {
            //store it in data
            dataStore = dataStore + buffer[i];                  
        }  
        if(buffer[i] == "N")
         {
            //spit the data
            //console.log(dataStore);           
            //socket.emit('data', {'salutation':dataStore});    
            socket.emit('data', dataStore);    
            // //initialize data to null    
            dataStore = "";
         }
    }           
  });       
});
```

**Below is the client code which tries to use Flot to display realtime charts**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
        <title>Chat</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <script type='text/javascript'     
            src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../3rdParty/flot/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../3rdParty/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="//localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function () {         
        // Initialize Flot data points
        var totalPoints = 300;
        var res = [];
        function getInitData() {
            // zip the generated y values with the x values
            for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints; ++i){
                res.push([i, 0]);
            }
            return res;
        }

        // Options for Flot plot
        var options = {
            series: { shadowSize: 0 }, // drawing is faster without shadows
            yaxis: { min: 0, max: 100 },
            xaxis: { show: false }
        };
        var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ getInitData() ], options);

        // Update the JQuery UI Progress Bar
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: 0
        });

        //var socket = io.connect();
        //var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
        //var socket = io.connect(document.location.href);
         var socket = io.connect('http://10.0.0.2:8000');

        //This block is executed when data is received from server
        socket.on('data', function(msg) {                   
            // Put sensor value to the 'sensor_value' span
            //var val = data.salutation;
            var val = msg;
            $('#sensor_value').html(val);

            // Push new value to Flot Plot
            res.push([totalPoints, val]); // push on the end side
            res.shift(); // remove first value to maintain 300 points
            // reinitialize the x axis data points to 0 to 299.
            for (i=0;i<totalPoints;i++) { res[i][0] = i; }

            // Redraw the plot
                plot.setData([ res ]);
                plot.draw();
                // Update JQuery UI progress bar.
                $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                    value: val
                });
        });

    });
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Temperature Monitor</h1>
    <div role="main">
        Potentiometer Value: <span id="sensor_value"></span><br/>
    <div id="progressbar" style="width:600px;height:50px;"></div><br/>
    Graph:<br/>
        <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div><br/>         
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me out why flot is not working in my setup ?
Also I am running server and client on same machine which is windows 7.

In the chrome debugger I could see the following message :

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8000/3rdParty/flot/jquery.js". :8000/:6
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8000/3rdParty/flot/jquery.flot.js". :8000/:6
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8000/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css". localhost:5
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.js:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.flot.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (i,r){return new b.fn.init(i,r)} has no method 'plot' localhost:31
```

Any help will be very highly appreciated.

Cheers !
AN

Comment: Those errors mean two things:  1.) your server is not serving js files with with the correct MIME type.  2.) both jquery.js and flot.js are not being interpreted properly with an `Unexpected token` error.  Do as @thtsigma recommends below and make sure you can get to those js files properly from your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

I would just have made a comment, but I don't have enough rep for that.  Maybe this will help, I don't know.

Modifying

```
<script src="//localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

got rid of the debug thing for me...also moving

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
```

to be right under the function seemed to allow the console to spit out some more debug statements..

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {         
     var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
    // Initialize Flot data points
    var totalPoints = 300;
```

Comment: Hi thtsigma, After making the above two changes, I could see more debug messages. The debug message indicate that data is being received from the serial port. But realtime graph is still not displayed.

Comment: Also in Chrome debugger I could see following error messages :      **Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'progressbar'                        **Uncaught TypeError: Object function (i,r){return new b.fn.init(i,r)} has no method 'plot'

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that you weren't getting a graph displayed either.  You could check to make sure the script is getting loaded by checking the source code in the browser and clicking the link to the script and see if it shows the source of the script.

Comment: Also, I was having problems getting the chart itself... but if I copy and paste those huge JS scripts in the template2.htm the graph itself will show.  although you'll have a huge template.htm.. that should at least get you started, and from there you can play with it and see why its not including your .js scripts.